# How to dispose a sibling of parent widget on navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is the hierarchy of my widgets:

```
VideoPage
    VideoPlayer
    RelatedVideos
        VideoItem1
        VideoItem2
        VideoItem3
```

I am navigating to a new VideoPage whenever a VideoItem is clicked. My problem is that the VideoPlayer (Chewie) is not being disposed so the video keeps playing in the background.

**How would I go about disposing the VideoPlayer Widget from a VideoItem?**

I tried Navigator.pushReplacement but then I wouldn't be able to go back to a previous video.

This is a snippet of the code in the VideoItem widget that handles the navigation (the thumbnail is wrapped with a gesture detector which opens a new page when clicked):

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: (){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return VideoPage(
          file: file,
          thumbnail: thumbnail,
          title: videoTitle,
          id: id,
        );
      },
    ));
  },
  child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: 200.0,
    child: ExtendedImage.network(
      thumbnail,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      cache: true,
    )
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating the controllers inside `initState` in `VideoPage`? If so, try overriding `deactivate` in the same widget to `pause` and `dispose` of the controllers. This should happen when navigating away from a `VideoPage`.

You can then try to use `didUpdateWidget` to reinitialize any `controllers` that were disposed upon deactivation, by comparing the current controllers to the old widgets controllers passed in.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _videoPlayerController = new....
  _chewieController = new....
}

@override
void didUpdateWidget(VideoPage oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  if (widget._videoPlayerController != oldWidget._videoPlayerController) {
    // new controller here
  }
}

@override
void deactivate() {
  _videoPlayerController.pause();
  _videoPlayerController.dispose();
  _chewieController.dispose();
  super.deactivate();
}
```

Information about deactivate here: [Deactivate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/deactivate.html)

Comment: Overriding deactivate seems to have worked. I called pause() on both the ChewieController and the VideoController, but now I get this error: "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." when I go back to the previous video.

Comment: After trying your latest suggestion, I still got the error I was getting before but now I also get "A ChewieController was used after being disposed.". Here is the code for the VideoPlayer widget, please tell me if I followed your instructions correctly: https://gist.github.com/jinyus/4eb77d2e3de7487386506fc8f729cbd5

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the controllers back to the other view and dispose of them:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) {
    return VideoPage(
      file: file,
      thumbnail: thumbnail,
      title: videoTitle,
      id: id,
    );
  },
)).then((List<ChewieController> controllers){
  controllers.forEach((controller) => controller.dispose())
});
```

Comment: I have done this already, the problem is that the dispose method is not called when I use Navigator.push()...it's only called when I remove the route from the stack by calling Navigator.pushReplacement() instead but using this method doesn't allow going back to the previous video.

Comment: Worst case scenario you could pass the controllers to the next view and dispose of them there.

Comment: I've changed my answer to comply with my previous comment.

Comment: Tried that, it worked but it was just too messy. I used the method suggested by @yusef-ouda but I've hit another roadblock. edit:this comment was in response to your worst case scenario.

Comment: Yes, it does feel a bit messy.